# Need help configuring Exchange 2010 server certificate

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, certificate

I've set an a multi-role Exchange server (SVR1) for my office, and now I am setting up a second multi-role server (SVR2) in a different site. Outlook Anywhere is not activated, and I don't have an edge server. Setting up the DAG is easy enough, but I'm confused about the server certificates.

Currently users access OWA using the URL https://mail.mydomain.com. So SVR1 has a certificate containing SANs for SVR1.mydomain.com and mail.mydomain.com.

But what about SVR2? What should the Certificate Principal Name, and Subject Alternative Names be?

Comment: If the certificate is for the edge server they should both be the same for CPN and SAN.  ideally if you were using both servers as edge servers they would answer for OWA/Outlook Anywhere which would need to have the same names.